# Google Spreadsheet, Select rows based on occurrence in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a *sheet* with these rows:

```
# Sheet1
A       B
-       -
White   1 
Gray    2 
Pink    3 
Red     4 
Brown   5
```

An this is another *sheet* that acts as a filter:

```
# Sheet2
A
-
Gray
Pink
```

I would like to have a third *sheet* with the rows in `Sheet1` which column value `A` is not included in `Sheet2!A`:

```
# Sheet3
A       B
-       -
White   1
Red     4
Brown   5
```

I'm trying with `filter`, `query`, `arrayformula`, .. but I don't get with the proper combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A,0)))`

You can get an idea of how this works by invoking just the MATCH part in a spare cell in row 1:

`=ArrayFormula(MATCH(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A,0))`